# Google calendar: last Saturday in February, each year?

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar, I can see how to set up an event for the last Saturday in the month, and I can see how to set an event annually for a specific date (say, February 23rd), but what I'd like to do is set an event for - picking an arbitrary example - the last Saturday in February, each year.

It doesn't seem to be do-able using the regular web interface, but is this possible by other means?